# Swift: Custom Annotation Loses Subtitle

Tags: swift, properties, delegates, mkmapview, mkannotation

I create a custom annotation and then place it on the map. Then when I select it, it does not have a subtitle property value anymore and it loses the info property.

**Custom Annotation:**

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class GAPoint: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var title: String?
    var subTitle: String?
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var info: String

    init(title: String, subTitle: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, info: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.subTitle = subTitle
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.info = info
    }
}
```

**Placing it on Map:**

```
var titles = ["title1", "title2"]
var ids = ["id1", "id2"]

for i in 0...1 {
    // Create Annotation Array
    let point = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:
         fences[i].CENTER_LAT, longitude: fences[i].CENTER_LONG)
    //Now use this point to add annotation on map.
    let title = titles[i]
    let id = ids[i]
    let annotation = GAPoint(title: title, subTitle: id, 
         coordinate: point, info: id)
    annotations.append(annotation)
}

// Add Annotation to map
self.mapView?.addAnnotations(annotations)
```

**Called when Annotation is Added:**

```
// Annotation View Properties (Pin Added or Moved) ---------------------
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    print("mv viewFor Annotation: Pin Added or Moved")
    // If Annotation (Pin) is Not GAPoint Don't Add
    guard annotation is GAPoint else { return nil }
    if let identifier = annotation.title {
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier!)
        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            //annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
            annotationView?.isDraggable = true
            // Create Label
            let annotationLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: -75, y: -8, width: 150, height: 20))
            annotationLabel.numberOfLines = 1
            annotationLabel.textAlignment = .center
            annotationLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 10)
            annotationLabel.text = identifier
            annotationLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            annotationLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            annotationLabel.clipsToBounds = true
            annotationView?.addSubview(annotationLabel)
            //annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: "gaPin.png")
        } else {
            annotationView?.annotation = annotation
        }
        return annotationView
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

**Called when annotation is selected:**
(This is where the subtitle value is missing
and the info property has disappeared)

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    print("mv didSelect view: Selected a pin")
    guard view.annotation is GAPoint else { return }
    if let annotation = view.annotation {
        if let title1 = annotation.title {
            if let title = title1 {
                print(title)
            }
        }
        if let stitle1 = annotation.subtitle {
            if let stitle = stitle1 {
                print(stitle)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You ever figure out the cause? Am running into exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and then tried to cast annotation as GAPoint with the
**following code:**

```
let loc : GAPoint = annotation as! GAPoint
```

**In context of delegate:**

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {

        print("mv didSelect view: Selected a pin")
        guard view.annotation is GAPoint else { return }
        
        if let annotation = view.annotation {
            let loc : GAPoint = annotation as! GAPoint
            if let title1 = annotation.title {
                if let title = title1 {
                    print(title)
                }
            }
            if let stitle1 = annotation.subtitle {
                if let stitle = stitle1 {
                    print(stitle)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```